# Wcf library in Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm using wcf library in windows service my wcf libray contain one project dll which contains data access layer. When I try to start my windows service then my windows service is unable to start

Exception :

> Service cannot be started.
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException:
>   The server was unable to process the
>   request due to an internal error.  For
>   more information about the error,
>   either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either
>   from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from
>   the  configuration
>   behavior) on the server in order to
>   send the exception information back to
>   the client, or turn on tracing as per
>   the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK
>   documentation and inspect the server
>   trace logs.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String
>   action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(...

For this we use    in App Config

My service call is

```
using (ServiceReference1.Service1Client c = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
            {
                c.GetZvol();
                c.ChannelFactory.Close();
                c.Close();
            }
```

But after adding this it givs another Exception while starting windows service

Exception :

> Service cannot be started.
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException:
>   The communication object,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel,
>   cannot be used for communication
>   because it is in the Faulted state.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.Close()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
>   at ClassDemo.Class1.CreateFile() in
>   C:\Users\vikram\Documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\mcWindowsService\ClassDemo\Class1.cs:line
>   21    at
>   mcWindowsService.Service1.OnStart(String[]
>   args) ...

Please anyone tell me the solution

Answer (score 1):

You cant host and call a wcf service from the same process. Your windows service should only host the wcf dll and you can make calls to it from another process like a winforms app or web app.

Comment: i m workig on the Cloud computing backuputility in that i have using the windows service which monitoring on the databse and this database monitoring business logic containing in the wcf service thats why i need to host and call that service from windows service is their another solution

Comment: look at this thread How to communicate with a WCF service from its host Window Service itself: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/4943d3f6-99ba-4af4-9a96-89b117402f02

Comment: here i hosting my service on onstart event of windows service and in this windows service i use the another project dll in that project we add the that service reference which is hosted in the onstart event and that wcf containing another project dll this dll containing the dataacces layer code . if you can't able to understand if you have no mention please send me your mail id i have send my application to you thanks

Comment: here i can't able to connect from my windows service to SQL server